# Symfony 3 - Forms - Persist Entity - Choices are NULL

Tags: forms, orm, entity, symfony, persist

I'm new to Symfony and cannot easily find Symfony 3 answers to my question.

Problem : 
I have a basic form setup which populates select boxes with basic id+name Entity values (Country, Company, Partner, etc.)

All the select boxes are correctly populated from the DB.
However when I try saving the populated form, all the "choices" are returned as null.

Question : 
What am i missing to make sure the selected values in the selectboxes are sent through to the INSERT statement ?

Note : I have looked at the [Form documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html) but that didn't seem to cover this scenario.

Form : 
[image: Populated form]

Result on Submit : 
[image: Submit result]

**Controller excerpt :**

```
/**
 * @Route("/opportunity/add", name="add_opportunity")
 */
public function addAction(Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $opportunity = new Opportunity();
    $form = $this->createForm(OpportunityType::class, $opportunity);

    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

        $em->persist($opportunity);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('/opportunity/add');
    }

    return $this->render(
        'opportunity/add-opportunity.html.twig',
        array('form' => $form->createView())
    );
}
```

**Build Form from OpportunityType :**

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('name', TextType::class)

        ->add('countries', EntityType::class, array(
            'class' => 'AppBundle:Country',
            'choice_label' => 'name'
        ))

        ->add('partners', EntityType::class, array(
            'class' => 'AppBundle:Partner',
            'choice_label' => 'name'
        ))

        ->add('companies', EntityType::class, array(
            'class' => 'AppBundle:Company',
            'choice_label' => 'name'
        ))

        ->add('users', EntityType::class, array(
            'class' => 'AppBundle:User',
            'choice_label' => 'name'
        ))

        ->add('stages', EntityType::class, array(
            'class' => 'AppBundle:Stage',
            'choice_label' => 'name'
        ))

        ->add('stage_changed_date', DateType::class)
        ->add('target_close_date', DateType::class)
        ->add('contract_value', TextType::class)

    ;
}
```

**Form twig :**

```
{% block body %}
<div style="max-width: 600px; margin-top:100px; padding:15px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;" class="card">
{{ form_start(form) }}
    <div class="form-header purple darken-4">
        <h3><i class="fa"></i>Add Opportunity</h3>
    </div>
    {{ form_row(form.name) }}
    {{ form_row(form.countries) }}
    {{ form_row(form.partners) }}
    {{ form_row(form.companies) }}
    {{ form_row(form.users) }}
    {{ form_row(form.stages) }}
    {{ form_row(form.stage_changed_date) }}
    {{ form_row(form.target_close_date) }}
    {{ form_row(form.contract_value) }}

    <button class="btn btn-raised btn-primary" type="submit">ADD</button>
{{ form_end(form) }}
</div>
```

{% endblock %}

Comment: How are you defining your entities and relations between them ?

Comment: At the moment all the entities are straightforward ORM table-mapped, with "id" and "name".
I may be missing inter-entity relationships.
But in this case, I dont need to persist other entities.
The "opportunity" table stores ids of the other values.
The dropdown for each has the "id" as the "value", and i want to persist that actual "id" not the Entity Country.
(working insert)
INSERT INTO opportunity (name, partner_id, country_id, company_id, user_id, stage_id, stage_changed_date, target_close_date, contract_value) VALUES ("Test", 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, "2016-01-01", "2016-12-12)

Comment: @ChuckNorris
Okay some debugging revealed that the submission result has _objects_ for each of the dropdowns instead of the selected string value. 
i.e. the result has : 
`country_id = null` and `countries = [object]` (which has the correct selected value)`
So maybe your comment about relationships is something I have to look at. I'll read up the core documentation, but any suggestions would be extremely helpful. Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved, and probably not the best solution, but something which may be helpful to others.

I ended up just assigning the values as needed on the Opportunity object after Form submission before db persistence :

```
$form->handleRequest($request);
if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

    // Get selected values for dropdowns
    $opportunity->setPartnerId($opportunity->getPartners()->getId());
    $opportunity->setCountryId($opportunity->getCountries()->getId());
    $opportunity->setCompanyId($opportunity->getCompanies()->getId());
    $opportunity->setUserId($opportunity->getUsers()->getId());
    $opportunity->setStageId($opportunity->getStages()->getId());

    $em->persist($opportunity);
    $em->flush();

    return $this->redirectToRoute('add_opportunity');
}
```

Comment: Hi, I've juste added a working examle with entities relations.
It allows you to have a cleaner code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, since in your formType, each of your field is an EntityType class, I think Symfony is waiting for an entity.
So you have to create a realtion between entity Oppotunity and its "sub fields".

If you don't want to create relation in your entity, maybe try somthing like [Symfony2 Form Builder - creating an array of choices from a DB query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22856476/symfony2-form-builder-creating-an-array-of-choices-from-a-db-query)

---

**Edit - adding example**

You can show a working example here :
https://gitlab.com/gaea44/test-form

Comment: Thanks for commenting further. I'm experimenting with those mappings now. For Opportunity (main object which has ids of the others) I've added these annotations to the foreign id fields : 
`* @ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Partner")
* @JoinColumn(name="partner_id", referencedColumnName="id")`
But its still not using the entity values. Is there anything I need to add to the "reverse side" ? i.e. all the dropdown Entities ?

Comment: (for other folks) Note that the example above is for Symfony 2 and is different for Symfony 3

Comment: Its a Symfony 3 example