# How to populate Symfony form (select dropdown) by hand (from sql results) instead of using entities?

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

Is it possible to populate Symfony form (select dropdown) by hand (from sql results) instead of using entities?

Comment: Have a look there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22856476/symfony2-form-builder-creating-an-array-of-choices-from-a-db-query

Comment: thanks, looks promising

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just build an array of choices by hand, just like shown in [Symfony's ChoiceType Field Documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html)